# Micro web-framework for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I would like to develop a very simple web-application. Is there something similar to Flask from Python world for Kotlin?

I know there is for instance Kara framework, but it looks abandoned.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, any Java framework would work with Kotlin. E.g. [here's an example of Kotlin with JAX-RS](https://github.com/backpaper0/sandbox/blob/master/kotlin-jaxrs-example%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fapp%2FHello.kt) (A Java EE API provided here by Jersy)

Comment: I still need to look into Flask, but if it works pretty much how I think it does, there's a Java framework that would also work well for Kotlin called Java Spark (not to be confused with Apache Spark). It's a micro framework that pretty much just encapsulates routing.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/Kotlin/ktor is the most popular kotlin web framework. Also look at this site https://kotlin.link/

Comment: I am the author of http://hexagonkt.com . Another easy to use library for coding backend software in Kotlin.

Comment: Questions like this belong on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any java micro web-framework for this purpose.

Personally i recommended [Spark Java](http://sparkjava.com/).
Also you can use [undertow](http://undertow.io/), [rapidoid](http://www.rapidoid.org/), [ratpack](https://ratpack.io/), etc.

An other option - [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin), which is lightweight too, see [post about memory consumption](https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/10/spring-boot-memory-performance).

Comment: http://www.pippo.ro/ or http://jooby.org also fit the bill

Comment: I googled and found Ktor, Wasabi and TornadoFX.

Answer (score 9):

This is this great (curated) list of Kotlin goodness: https://github.com/KotlinBy/awesome-kotlin and there are some web frameworks as well.

Great place to visit every now and then and see what is new.